# ASP.NET - Request.Cookies no longer working in Chrome V80+

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, cookies, samesite

In what is undoubtedly related to the Chromes samesite cookie policies released recently I am now having issues updating cookies in ASP.NET.

---

I have a simple cookie collection to store basic user settings.
The cookie is both generated and updated using the code below.

**SET COOKIE**

```
If Response.Cookies("Settings") IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim cookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Settings")
  cookie("Setting01") = ddl.SelectedValue
  cookie.Expires = Date.Now.AddDays(365)
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
End If
```

When the cookie is first created it appears correctly as below.

[image]

When the setting is updated and the code above called a second time the value is removed.

[image]

---

This only occurs in Chrome and only since I updated to Chrome V84

I have made the following recent changes in web.config to accommodate samesite requirements.

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" cookieSameSite="None" />
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```

---

**WHERE IS THE ISSUE?**

It is this part of the code that now returns nothing

```
Request.Cookies("Settings")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

This issue was caused by not explicitly setting the `SameSiteMode` in code behind when creating a new cookie.

```
If Response.Cookies("Settings") IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim cookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Settings")
  cookie("Setting01") = ddl.SelectedValue
  cookie.Expires = Date.Now.AddDays(365)

  cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax

  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
End If
```

Additionally setting `SameSiteMode.None` will not work. Presemuably to enforce that this cookie originated from the samesite.

---

**BUT WHY?**

I still don't fully understand why this is the case because if you set in web.config

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" sameSite="Lax" requireSSL="true" />
```

Then your newly created cookies are flagged as Lax in the Chrome and changing this setting is reflected like below:

[image]

However if you now try to read that cookie from code behind it's value will be erased.
This is not the case is you exclusively set it in code behind.

I am not sure what makes the cookie different and is more likely an issue with the way .NET is handling this.

---

Any additional intel on this answer would be intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug. 11, 2020, Chromium is now targeting 100% of users with SameSite cookie changes. (source: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site)

SameSite cookies FAQ: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/faq